# Java Script with Delphi Program

Tags: javascript, delphi, delphi-7

How will use googiespell script with Delphi Program with WebBrowser. Script is for spell checker. My code is for using java script inside Webbrowser.

This is code for executing script.

```
uses
  MSHTML_TLB, SHDocVw, ShellAPI;

function ExecuteScript(doc: IHTMLDocument2; script: string; language: string): Boolean;
var
  win: IHTMLWindow2;
  Olelanguage: Olevariant;
begin
  if doc <> nil then
  begin
    try
      win := doc.parentWindow;
      if win <> nil then
      begin
        try
          Olelanguage := language;
          win.ExecScript(script, Olelanguage);
        finally
          win := nil;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      doc := nil;
    end;
  end;
end;


Sample usage:

IDoc: IHTMLDocument2;
Webbrowser1.Document.QueryInterface(IHTMLDocument2, iDoc);
ExecuteScript(iDoc, 'document.login.submit()', 'JavaScript');
```

So I need to use googiespell script for spell checker with webbrowser. Please help me.?

You can download googiespell script from [this](http://orangoo.com/labs/GoogieSpell/Download/) site

Comment: ok "ExecuteScript" will work only with specific html file. Can I see this HTML file? You suppose to have it and this file suppose to  have spell checker connected and probably has some entering form available. This file is vital for the task.